# How to retrieve Walmart Products from API

Tags: api, product

I'm developing a project in which I need to retrieve Walmart products from product categories using the API.

I'm getting my API token from platform REST Web services here:
https://app.impact.com/

However, when I use the walmart API I'm getting an account inactive message.

Please help. This is the call I'm making.

http://api.walmartlabs.com/v1/taxonomy?apiKey=x-ct5_pLDzZAcREhmsiqfqgpQPkGK4gt&format=json

Comment: Is your account inactive? Are you sure your account is allowed to call the Walmart API?

You probably also shouldn't post your API key on a public website...

Comment: That's the thing, I've now registered at two different locations...both have given me an API key for Walmart, yet neither work.  One is Walmart.io and the other is the impact website.  It's very confusing.  Is there separate registration that I need?  On the developer.walmart site it says registration is blocked.